# Why isn't my nested state path in Angular UI-Router working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get one thing to show when the user visits

`mysite.com/projects`

and another thing to show when they visit

`mysite.com/projects/project`

However, despite following the tutorial in the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), my set up won't work.

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong? I've looked at everything and compared character for character with the official docs.

[See my Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sfpA0eX1nPqHAXCFdCNf?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your exemple.

First, your link to the `projects.project` state is incorrect. You need to put the full name of the state in the `ui-sref` attribute, so `projects.project`.

Next, your trying to use nested state. When navigating to the `projects.project` state, the `projects.project` state will not replace the `projects` state. In fact, the `projects` state will host the child state. So you need to add the `ui-view` directive inside your `projects` template (the `r1.html` file).

Here is a functionnal Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LyBM4QiKiw8sAoI0jiKo

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing concepts in your states.  In some places you are referencing `/project` as it's own state, in others you are trying to reference it as a child state of `/projects`.

You can only use `projects.project` when you are embedding the contents of the child within the template of the parent.

I created two forks of your Plunkr, showing both independent routes and parent/child routes.

Note in the parent/child route, there is an additional `<div ui-view></div>` in the parent template.

Singular routes: http://plnkr.co/edit/jIMcdTuifE8oRpg83vtN?p=preview.

Parent/child: http://plnkr.co/edit/A85svCnngB7x4PJCUUf9?p=preview

Comment: "You can only use projects.project when you are embedding the contents of the child within the template of the parent." I don't see how you embedded the contents within the parent.

Comment: in the second example, the addition of the ui-view in the parent template allows the child page to load within it.